# Standard Normal Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

[image]

I am setting this problem up as P(-2 < (Mn) < 2) and then plugged in the formula for mean and standard deviation. I don't feel like I am headed in the correct direction. Could someone set me straight?

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve for

$$P(|M_n| \ge 2) \le \frac1{100}$$

Note that mean of $M_n=0$,

Hence this reduces to

$$P(M_n \le -2) \le \frac1{200}$$

You might like to find the standard deviation of $M_n$ to proceed with the question.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But how do you go from there to solve for n without know what the sum of the X's are?

Comment: Can you express the problem in the form of $P(Z \le \alpha_n) \le \frac1{200}$ where $\alpha_n$ depends on $n$ and $Z$ is the standard normal distribution?  from the inverse CDF value, try to figure out a bound for $\alpha_n$?